# What Google services does WhatsApp depends on?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, google-apps

WhatsApp is the only Google-dependent app on my phone. I was removing various Google services from it with adb and as a result, WhatsApp is the only app that doesn't work - it crashes instantly on any interaction.

My fault is that I don't remember all the services I uninstalled, but here are some:
`gsf`, `gms`, `gmsconfig.asi`, `gmsconfig.gsa`, `gmsconfig.comms`, and more.

Which Google services does WhatsApp depend on? Maybe I would just sideload them for the time I plan to use WhatsApp.

Comment: At the very least, I believe the "Google Play Services" app is used for push notifications using FCM.

Comment: See logcat when the app crashes.